# UnboundID vs Apache LDAP APIS

Tags: ldap

I have been exploring libraries to use for LDAP operations and i am considering using Unbounded or Apache LDAP API.

We expect about a million users registering with our service and using it on day to day basis. Active Directory will serve as LDAP server for us.

I would appreciate if somebody can point me out as to which one of these API's should be used?

My main goal is Performance, stability and active community for the products.

PS: i cannot use Spring LDAP API or JNDI and the choice is restricted between these two options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UnboundId seems to be better. I used Apache initially and had to rewrite a hell lot of code, there are performance issues with Apache and close connection method has bug as well. It just seems to be slow.

Answer (score 0):

I think both will serve your needs. There is a 3rd option, which is OpenDJ LDAP API, opendj.forgerock.org.

What should matter is the license under which the API is available, and how actively it is developed.

Regards.

Ludovic